# How to use a custom Qt type with a QML signal?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I've created a custom type inside my Qt 5.2 qml application

```
class Setting : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString key READ key WRITE setKey)
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariant value READ value WRITE setValue)

public:
    Setting(QObject * parent = 0);

    QString key() const;
    void setKey(QString const & key);

    QVariant value() const;
    void setValue(QVariant const & value);

private:
    QString m_key;
    QVariant m_value;
};
```

and registered it in my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<Setting>("Setting", 1,0, "Setting");

    // ...
}
```

In my application I would like to have a button that has a signal with my custom type as a parameter:

```
import Setting 1.0

Button
{
    signal settingChanged(string, Setting)

    // ...
}
```

Every time I hit the button the signal should be emitted.

If I try to connect my qml signal with my C++ slot

```
QObject::connect(myButton, SIGNAL(settingChanged(QString, Setting)), this, SLOT(settingChanged(QString, Setting)));
```

Qt says

```
QObject::connect: No such signal Button_QMLTYPE_41_QML_45::settingChanged(QString, Setting) in ...
```

If I remove my custom type from the signal definition

```
Button
{
    signal settingChanged(string)

    // ...
}
```

and modify the connect call

```
QObject::connect(myButton, SIGNAL(settingChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(settingChanged(QString)));
```

the connect call worked.

I could use my custom qml type *Setting* inside the qml part of my application. But what I do wrong if I would like to use it with my signal *settingChanged*?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you put the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Setting)` macro at the end of your class declaration?

Comment: @Nejat I don't have this macro defined. But when I put Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Setting) at the end of my class declaration, the result is the same as described in my question. So, nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I've readed the Qt documentation very carefully, I've found the answer here

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html#connecting-to-qml-signals

The documentation says

> *When a QML object type is used as a signal parameter, the parameter*
>   *should use var as the type, and the value should be received in C++*
>   *using the QVariant type.*

So, the signal definition inside the qml description of `Setting` has to be replaced with `var`.

```
import Setting 1.0

Button
{
    signal settingChanged(string, var)

    // ...
}
```

To connect the qml signal with the C++ slot, the code has to be

```
Object::connect(myButton, SIGNAL(settingChanged(QString, QVariant)), this, SLOT(settingChanged(QString, QVariant)));
```

At this point the connection worked!

To make the whole thing running, the `QVariant` has to be casted to the right type inside the slot. In my case to a `Setting` type.

```
void Foo::settingChanged(QString name, QVariant const & var)
{
    Setting * setting = qobject_cast<Setting*>(var.value<QObject*>());

    // ...
}
```