# How to use a custom Qt C++ type with a QML slot?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to use my C++ type registered in QML as parameter in QML slot. So I already have C++ signal which has QString type parameter:

```
emit newMessage(myString);
```

and QML slot:

```
onNewMessage: {
    console.log(myString);
}
```

Now I want to pass C++ type registered in QML as parameter of this slot.
I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25650594/how-to-use-a-custom-qt-type-with-a-qml-signal), but I don't understand how I can use this vice versa. Any help will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

So Lets say you wanted to pass a QObject derived file back and forth from C++ to QML  via a signal/slot setup.

```
  class MyClass : public QObject
  {
      Q_OBJECT
  public:
      explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = 0);


  signals:
      void sendSignal(MyClass* anotherMyClass)
  public slots:
       void  send_signals()  {   emit sendSignal(this); }
  };
```

If you have a C++ type  called   MyClass which is a QObject-based type, and you successfully did

```
    qmlRegisterType<MyClass>("com.myapp", 1, 0, "MyClass");
```

Then In QML  all you have to do is this:

```
  import QtQuick 2.0
  import com.myapp

  Item {
        MyClass {
              id: myInstance
              Component.OnCompleted: {
                  // connect signal to javascript function
                  myInstance.sendSignal.connect( myInstance.receiveSignal);
              }
              function receiveSignal(mySentObject) {
                      // here is your QObject sent via Signal
                      var  receivedObject = mySentObject;

                     // Now to send it back 
                    //  (will cause an endless loop)
                      myInstance.sendSignal(receivedObject);

                     //  or you could do this to perform 
                      // the same endless loop
                     receivedObject.send_signals();

                     //  or you could do this to perform 
                      // the same endless loop
                     receivedObject.sendSignal(myInstance)

               } 
      }
  }
```

Summary:

You can just send  any QObject-derived object as long as its registered with the QML engine as the actual object, you just treat it like any other type in QML

Hope this helps